# Is there any way to use the Text view from a layout resource file into an activity class?

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

In general I'm trying to create a ChatBot app but i don't have any code for reference and trying it myself.. so far I've completed the Sender msg part and updated it in firebase database.. Now how to make the receiver text appear once the sender text is updated?

I have seperate layout for sender msg part and receiver msg part and adapter java class and an recycler view in another activity

I thought of using the textview from receiver layout resource and use set text.. if that'd work someone tell me how to do that

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get you correctly but I'm assuming you mean you want messages to display on the left or on the right if so you can have 2 variables:

```
private static final int MESSAGE_RIGHT = 1;
private static final int MESSAGE_LEFT = 0;
```

then in your adapter you can call getItemViewType like so and make it such that you choose what type of view you want to be returned given the message type:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (messageList.get(position).getUid().equals(Common.CURRENT_USER_ID)){
        return MESSAGE_RIGHT;
    }else {
        return MESSAGE_LEFT;
    }
}
```

then after in your onCreateViewHolder you return a correct Viewholder for the specific message type whether its left or right like so:

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public DirectMessageAdapter.ViewHolderForDirectMessage onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == MESSAGE_LEFT){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.message_type_left_format, parent, false);
    }else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.message_type_right_format, parent, false);
    }
    return new ViewHolderForDirectMessage(view);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks! But, i don't have a Uid as this is just a chatbot app i didn't set up any authentication. Also if a message is entered it has to automatically show the message on the other side.. Do you have any idea about that?